# custom object rules inside Makefile.am for automake

Tags: autoconf, automake

Typical makefile.am, which works, would look like this for my project:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libwinsane.la

CLEANFILES = init.cpp

libwinsane_la_CXXFLAGS = \
  -I$(top_srcdir)
libwinsane_la_SOURCES = \
  init.cpp
noinst_HEADERS = \
  init.h
```

the issue is that I need to also process resource files. I need to use something like this:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libwinsane.la

libwinsane.o: init.o manifest.o
    ld -relocatable -o $@ init.o manifest.o

manifest.o: manifest.rc utf8.xml
    windres -o $@ manifest.rc

clean:
    rm -f init.o manifest.o libwinsane.o
```

While this last example is valid makefile by itself (except noinst_LIBRARIES), its obviously wrong syntax for automake. But maybe there is a way for automake to just accept it and produce library in the end somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, and without 100% verifying its consistency with https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-and-Library-Variables.html or testing it, something like this should work more or less:

```
CLEANFILES =

noinst_LTLIBRARIES          = libwinsane.la
libwinsane_la_SOURCES       =
libwinsane_la_SOURCES      += init.cpp
libwinsane_la_SOURCES      += init.h
libwinsane_la_CXXFLAGS      = -I$(top_srcdir)

libwinsane_la_DEPENDENCIES  = manifest.$(OBJEXT)
libwinsane_la_LIBADD        = manifest.$(OBJEXT)
CLEANFILES                 += manifest.$(OBJEXT)
manifest.$(OBJEXT): manifest.rc utf8.xml
        windres -o $@ $(srcdir)/manifest.rc
```

A few additional remarks:

- The `windres` recipe probably does not work for out of source builds if `utf8.xml` has not just been buitl in $(builddir) and is therefore located in `$(srcdir)`. Adding something like `-I $(srcdir)` to the `windres` command line will probably fix this, but cannot verify that without a MWE.
- You will want to make `windres` configurable and replace the hard coded `windres` call by `$(WINDRES)`, made user configurable by `AC_ARG_VAR` and (if `$WINDRES` has not been set) `AC_CHECK_TOOL`, and probably protected with a check in `configure.ac` that `$WINDRES` actually works. Depending on your project you can then either `AC_MSG_ERROR(...)` in case `$WINDRES` does not work, or `AM_CONDITIONAL([HAVE_WINDRES], ...)` and then put the `Makefile.am` parts related to `manifest.$(OBJEXT)` inside a `if HAVE_WINDRES` / `endif` conditional. The actual `windres` command might be called something like `x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres` when cross-compiling.
- Why do you have `CLEANFILES += init.cpp`? I have left that out, as you do not want `make clean` to delete your source files. Or does `init.cpp` belong to `BUILT_SOURCES`?

**Update:** Apparently, I have overlooked something for compiling and linking with libtool: [cannot build libtool library from non-libtool objects - any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72593009/cannot-build-libtool-library-from-non-libtool-objects-any-workaround)